# Detect screenshot being taken and disable specific app

Tags: tasker

I'm running twilight and screenshots end up being red.

I would like a way to detect the screenshot event and disable twilight before the actual screen capture.

My device is not rooted. But I'm open to rooting.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with  [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation app (free upto 5 macros) and real easy to learn

I modified a macro to take screenshots on shaking and added your Twilight app

[image]

Shaking the device takes shots (Trigger)

First action is Killing Twilight app ( requires **root** ) - alarm , pause, take screenshot, pause (adjustable for the time you think you would take a screen shot), launch Twilight app

Constraints -run this macro only when screen is on - so that you don't take screenshots while device is in pocket

After taking the screenshot you will be directed to Twilight page and not the page you were on - you need to switch to previous app

**Edit:** Here's a gif that shows Twilight being killed, screenshot taken and Twilight enabled on the Macro above

Go ahead and root, if you want this feature !

[image]

Comment: It looks like this solution requires `root` privileges, when the op stated they don't have it. I'm looking for a `non-root` solution as well. Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet AFAIK, not possible without root// OP was willing to root *My device is not rooted. But I'm open to rooting.*

Comment: I keep getting nagged by Tasker to install something which would give me root. The little blurb about it says that it's a special code you have to enter every time you boot the phone.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet I am sorry but I don't use Tasker at all so can't help with that but to "kill" an app you sure need root//You could probably ask another question using this as background and some Tasker wise guys can help

Comment: I expressed myself poorly. Tasker claims to give you root without jailbreaking the phone. If that is your need, I would give it a try.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet that's surprising to me. All the best and if you get stuck, you can also ask as a new question